# How can I fit these 3 columns into one?

Tags: database, database-design

For a project, I have a database with some tables.
All of them are related between them. The table organization has a relationship with offer and user, etc. 
However, I have some columns that only serve to link two tables together.
Take a look at the diagram. I use users_interests to link the user to his interests. Same thing for badges and group.

It doesn't really feel efficient. When I try to get the interests of a users, I must first go through requesting the user interests and from that, require the interest details.

Is there a way that I can request the interests of an user without having to go through a second table ?
https://dbdiagram.io/d/5da3f119ff5115114db53551

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple things you should consider when looking at this question/functionality and what you're going to be doing with the data.

- Do you have a unique set of `interests` that will remain the same or be added to,  without duplicates?
- Do you need to have multiple interests for a single user?

If you answered "yes" to both of these questions, then you should leave things the way they are. You'll be able to reuse the same `interests` entry for multiple users as well as each user being able to have multiple interests.

If you only want one interest per user, but want to keep a "master list" (aka: lookup table) of interests, then you can move the `interest_id` to the users table.

If you don't care about duplicates, but you still want each user to have multiple interests, move the `name` column to the `users_interests` table.

Finally, if you don't care about duplicates and you want each user to have a single interest, move the `name` column to the `users` table.

FYI, how you currently have the tables structured will likely take up less disk space for a large amount of users.

It's unclear what you're trying to do, so I included all options. Each option has it's own set of pros and cons, and each will be required of some other project or another at some point. You might want to learn the difference and reasoning behind why you would use one option over another now, so you don't have to think too hard about it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you will make interests like this

- id
- user_id
- name

but then you will lose uniqness of your interests, you will have many rows with the same name only because they connect to different users. Now db is perfectly ok according my understanding...It is as it should be